# battlEye launcher not launching fortnite

Tags: wine, games, crash

[image]

I tried to install Fortnite in Ubuntu with the help of this video (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pBdvza_u2Aw), but after all the steps when I launch Fortnite through epic launcher it doesn't launch even after waiting long

any help??

Answer (score 0):

As far as I'm aware of, I don't think BattleEye accepts Linux yet. I haven't heard any news about the progress on this since the pandemic sadly.

Comment: Oh thanks but the youtuber somehow managed it

Comment: I think the problem is when I had tried to use this command                                                 " sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-x-swat/updates"  but a problem like this comes up and says that the repository is not signed I tried it multiple times, but it seems not to work